# Javascript Performance Testing, identical tests at different speeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, testing

I've got some code for testing performance of jQuery selectors. I run the tests 3 times with 100000 repetitions in a browser console. The first test is always the slowest, then, the following two are nearly equal in speed. Has anybody an idea why?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/05xq70na/, the execution times are logged in browser console.

```
var repetitions = 100000;
var html = '<ul><li id="parent"><div id="child" class="child" value="test"></div></li></ul>';
var time = [];
var finished = false;

var tests = {

    "SelectorById": function(){
        var element;

        element = $("#child");
    },

    "SelectorByClass": function(){
        var element;

        element = $(".child");
    },

    "SelectorByTag": function(){
        var element;

        element = $("li");
    }
}

function showResults(loopCounter) {

    if(!finished) {
        finished = true;

        console.log("\nResults (" + loopCounter + " repetitions):");
        for(executionTime in time) {
            console.log(executionTime + ": " + (time[executionTime] / loopCounter) + " ms");
        }
    }   
}

function perform(test, string) {

    var startTime, 
        endTime,
        nextTest = tests[test];

    if(time[test + string] === undefined) {
        time[test + string] = 0;
    }

    startTime = performance.now();
    nextTest();
    endTime = performance.now();

    time[test + string] += (endTime - startTime);
}

function benchmark(tests) {

    for(var i=0, loopCounter=1; i<repetitions; i++) {

        // console.log('repetition ' + loopCounter);                

        for(test in tests) {

            // console.log('\texecute ' + test);

            perform(test, "1");
            perform(test, "2");
            perform(test, "3");

        }

        loopCounter++;

        if(loopCounter>repetitions) {

            showResults(--loopCounter);
        };
    }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = html;
benchmark(tests);
```

Comment: You can put the code on JSFiddle. Such that easier for others to get a fast interpretation of your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the simple jQuery selector in [JSLitmus](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfoa7sah/)).

```
JSLitmus.test('jQuery ID selector 1', function(counter) {
    while(counter--) {
        $('#test');
    }
});
...
```

The result is like:

[image]

The performance of ID selectors vary every time, but there is no fixed pattern.

I update your code to run every tests for 7 times: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05xq70na/1/). Then the first run also spends most time, however the rest spend some time comparable. Since JSLitmus performs something called calibration, I am afraid your testing code is not so fare, especially when there are so many function calls.

Comment: thanks for quick answer. My focus is more on why the code seems to be not so fare. Where's the problem... is it possible that v8 is doing some optimization after first run or something like that ?